# Removendo linhas duplicadas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, python-kivy

Estou desenvolvendo meu TCC,

Meu TCC, ele busca emails no google coleta, faz envio em massa etc,

Estou tendo um problema,
Nesta busca de emails ele coleta emails repetidos e emails não validos, ai eu estou realizando um separador de emails, gostaria de ajuda, já realizei o verificador de provedor, mas não estou conseguindo o mesmo remover os emails duplicados,

O Codigo esta assim:

```
print ("\nBUNITO\n")

palavra = input("Digite o provedor:")

arq = open('arquivo.txt','r')
contador = 0

for linha in arq:

    linha = linha.rstrip()
    if palavra in linha:
        contador = contador +1
        print(linha)
print ("\nForam Retornados", contador, "emails")
arq.close()
```

Se em minha lista tiver emails assim:

- 1@hotmail.com
- 1@hotmail.com
- 2@hotmail.com

ele deve apenas retornar assim:

- 1@hotmail.com
- 2@hotmail.com

Mas não estou conseguindo realizar isto.

Comment: Alguem, consegue me ajudar??

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
lista_duplicada = ['1@hotmail.com', '1@hotmail.com', '2@hotmail.com']
lista_unica = list(set(lista_duplicada))
print(lista_unica) 
# ['1@hotmail.com', '2@hotmail.com']
```

Comment: Ué pq editaste minha saudação? Não pode ser cordial?

Comment: Sei que pode parecer estranho, mas é de praxe remover saudações, saiba mais em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/851/112052